# Trimming and reformatting dates in R

Tags: r, date-conversion

I have a column of data with the following types of dates and number entries:

```
16-Jun
21-01A
7-04
Aug-99
5-09
```

I want to convert these all into numbers, by doing two things. First, where the data have a number before a dash (as in the first three examples), I want to trim the data from the dash onwards. So the entries would appear 16, 21 and 7.

Second, where the entry is written in month-date format (e.g. Aug-99), I want to convert that to the number of the month and then trim it. so this example, would be to convert the date to 8-99 then trim to just 8.

How can I do this in R? When I use grep, sub and match commands, as in the answer below, I get:
[1] 16 21  7  5  8

When I am after: [1] 16 21  7  8 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `grep` to find the index of elements that start with alphabets.  Remove the substring that starts from `-` to the end of the string with `sub`.  Subset the 'v2' based on 'i1' and convert to `numeric` while we `match` the ones starting with alphabets to `month.abb` and get the index of month, concatenate the output.

```
i1 <- grepl("^[A-Z]", v1)
v2 <- sub("-.*", "", v1)
c(as.numeric(v2[!i1]), match(v2[i1], month.abb))
#[1] 16 21  7  8
```

---

For the new dataset, we can use `ifelse`

```
i1 <- grepl("^[A-Z]", df1$v1)
v2 <- sub("-.*", "", df1$v1)
as.numeric(ifelse(i1, match(v2, month.abb), v2))
#[1] 16 21  7  8  5
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('16-Jun','21-01A','7-04','Aug-99') 
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("16-Jun", "21-01A", "7-04", "Aug-99", "5-09"
)), .Names = "v1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. This works in the example given. However, when using the last line of code to create a new column to the existing dataframe it is not assigning entries with a month correctly. Instead the new column skips over entries with abbreviated months and assigns the number for the next 'false' entry for the column 'code'.
This is my code for dataframe v1 and variable "class_code" (which is equivalent to v1)


v1$code <- grepl("^[A-Z]", v1$class_code)


v1$code2 <- sub("-.*", "", v1$class_code)


v1$code3 <- c(as.numeric(v1$code2[!v1$code]), match(v1$code2[v1$code], month.abb))

Comment: @ashomos Can you show a smal reproducible example using `dput` (to show the data) and update it in your post.  By reproducible, I meant it should show the problem that you encountered. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to input this, but in your example if you were to add another element to the column in v1 (use '5-09') after the last entry ('Aug-99') and re-run the code I get the following output "[1] 16 21 7 5 8"

The 8 should come before the 5, not the other way around. So the column that is created isn't returning the entries in the same order as listed in v1.
Does this make sense?

Comment: @ashomos Please update your post with an example that mimics the problem

Comment: @ashomos No problem, glad to help you.